# Max function returning multiple values [SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle, function, max

I have 3 tables: money, student, faculty. This query returns each faculty and highest stipend in each one of them.

```
select 
    f.name as "FACULTY_NAME",
    max(stipend) as "MAX_STIPEND"
from 
    money m, student s 
inner join
    faculty f on f.id_faculty = s.faculty_id
where 
    m.student_id = s.id_student
group by 
    f.id_faculty, f.name;
```

Query works fine:

```
FACULTY_NAME     |    MAX_STIPEND
-----------------+---------------
IT Faculty       |    50
Architecture     |    60
Journalism       |    40
```

However when I add s.name to original query to also show the name of the student who received max_stipend, query is not working like it used to - it returns all of the students

```
select 
    f.name as "FACULTY_NAME",s.name,
    max(stipend) as "MAX_STIPEND"
from 
    money m, student s 
inner join
    faculty f on f.id_faculty = s.faculty_id
where 
    m.student_id = s.id_student
group by 
    f.id_faculty, f.name, s.name;
```

Query result:

```
FACULTY_NAME    |   s.name  |   MAX_STIPEND
----------------+-----------+---------------
IT Faculty      |   Joe     |   50
IT Faculty      |   Lisa    |   10
Architecture    |   Bob     |   60
Journalism      |   Fred    |   5
Architecture    |   Susan   |   5
Journalism      |   Tom     |   40
```

It does the same thing using right, left and inner joins. Can someone tell where the problem is?

Comment: Pick one join syntax and stick with it, for starters. Preferably the one that uses the JOIN keyword.

Comment: Left justified SQL is just too hard to read.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Which rdbms are you using ?

Comment: I use oracle sqplus

Comment: Which table does stipend come from?

Comment: Table money contains stipend, student_id

Comment: @jarlh it's hard to read because the join syntax is garbled and `inner join` (the 'inner' keyword being redundant) is at the left margin. But at least it isn't in block capitals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be using proper `JOIN` syntax for *all* your joins.

Second, you can use Oracle's `keep` syntax:

```
select f.name as FACULTY_NAME,
       max(stipend) as MAX_STIPEND,
       max(s.name) keep (dense_rank first order by stipend desc)
from money m join
     student s 
     on  m.student_id = s.id_student join
     faculty f
     on f.id_faculty = s.faculty_id   
group by f.id_faculty, f.name;
```

Comment: all time learning from you @gordonLinoff. Nice answer. `keep`. nice.

Answer (score 0):

> However when I add s.name to original query to also show the name of the student who received max_stipend, query is not working like it used to - it returns all of the students

When you add `s.name` you are looking for min value for each user.

If you want the name of user who has the `MAX_STIPEND` you should to move to  window functions. For example [Dense Rank](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in MS SQL Server.

```
with cte as
(select 
    f.name as "FACULTY_NAME",
    s.name as "STUDENT_NAME",
    stipend as "MAX_STIPEND",
    DENSE_RANK() OVER   
    (PARTITION BY f.name, s.name ORDER BY i.stipend DESC) AS Rank  
 from 
    money m 
 inner join student s on m.student_id = s.id_student
 inner join
    faculty f on f.id_faculty = s.faculty_id
)
select "FACULTY_NAME", "STUDENT_NAME"
from cte
where rank = 1
```

Not all sql brands have windowed functions. Here the link for [dense_rank on MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) and also [dense_Rank for Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm)